# display nsmutablearray string with delay in uitextview

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsmutablearray

I want to update the contents of this UITextView with this NSMutable array by adding some delay to it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];
myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"String1",@"String2",@"String3",@"String4", @"String5",..... nil];                                                                                                                                        



int index = arc4random() % [myArray count];

myTextView.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
```

I want to display this NSMutable array one after other with some delay in UITextView.

Is there some way to display array in UITextView with some delay.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why you should use a timer

The *correct way* of doing this would be to use a repeating timer. The timer is configured to repeat and call a certain method every second.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateText:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

Inside your (new) `updateText` method you would generate the random number and update the text.

```
- (void)updateText:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    int index = arc4random() % [myArray count];
    myTextView.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

This is a clean solution that is almost self documenting.

---

## Why you *shouldn't* loop and perform after delay.

It is true that you *could* do this with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` or `dispatch_after()` but it is a easy to get wrong and is the actual working solution is more complex and harder to understand.

If you think that you can just loop a certain number of times and inside call either of these then you are going to see something funny. Both these methods are asynchronous and will not wait for the call to be called. They are merely scheduling it to happen a specified time from "now".

### What looping and calling asynchronous methods do

```
Loop 
 0    |----- 1s wait -----| |update|
 1     |----- 1s wait -----| |update|
 2      |----- 1s wait -----| |update|
 3       |----- 1s wait -----| |update|
    ...
 ----------- time --------------------->
```

The result of this, as you can imagine, is that nothing will happen for one second. Then all the scheduled calls are going to happen all at once.

This is actually equal to performing the entire loop after one second.

```
 |----- 1s wait -----| Loop:
                         0  |update|
                         1   |update|
                         2    |update|
                         3     |update|
                            ...
 ----------- time --------------------->
```

You could make this work if you instead scheduled the next call after each update

```
 |----- 1s wait -----| |update| |----- 1s wait -----| |update| ...
 ----------- time --------------------->
```

For this to happen you would have to schedule the next update in the previous update.

```
- (void)updateText {
    int index = arc4random() % [myArray count];
    myTextView.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateText) 
               withObject:nil
               afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

This would do the exact same thing as the repeating timer but has two main disadvantages.

**1) It is less intuitive.**

In the timer example you would only have to read the timer code to understand that the text would update every second. In this case you would just call `updateText`. It is not intuitive by reading that code without looking at the implementation of updateText that this is a repeating process.

**2) It gets even more complex if you want it to stop.**

You can keep a pointer to an `NSTimer` and make it stop by simply calling `[myTimer invalidate];`. The code that uses either `performSelector:...` or `dispatch_after()` doesn't yet support it and if it was built to support that it would be even more complex and less intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer with detailed explanation. Appreciate it. Instead of doing it random can i update the text serial wise one after the other in UITextView.

Comment: @user1452248 That you can do in a number of ways. You could add an argument (the index) to the update method and invalidate the timer once the array is over. You could also keep track of the current index and increment it or you could even use the array as a queue and remove the first object until the array is empty.

Comment: @user1452248 Sorry I forgot to add the timer argument to the updateText method. I've updated the answer.

Comment: i coded like this but not working. can u help please int index = [array count];
    
    for(int i = index; i < array.count; i++){
                                         
    self.textView.text = [array objectAtIndex:i];

Comment: i want to do it serial wise string1 then string2 and so on than randomly but with the above code it is not working at all can u please help. thanks

Comment: @user1452248 Skip the loop and use the code above. Just change the `int index = arc4random...` line to instead increment the current index. You can store that index in an instance variable. `currentIndex++;`

Answer (score 2):

Few ways to do, answer ranked according to my preference:

1.. You can use :

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

---

2.. [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) will also be serve you.

Comment: And the result will be that after I one second it changes very quickly through all of the strings.

Comment: That method is asynchronous so the loop will happen super quickly and schedule all the calls one second in the future and not one second from each other.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist : I think I missed to write full answer, now you can see, my both the answers.

Comment: A repeating timer is a correct solution to this but making asynchronous calls inside a loop is most likely never what you want to do.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist : I agree. I wanted to present all the possible ways to do.

Comment: Thanks for your help by providing possible solutions. Appreciate your time and help for this issue.